# Simple while loop getting stuck

Tags: javascript

I am attempting one of reddits daily programmer challenges and for some reason my seemingly correct and simple code seems to be getting stuck.
 [Here is a link to the challenge I am doing](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/3r7wxz/20151102_challenge_239_easy_a_game_of_threes/)

```
function play() {
  var start = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var number = parseInt(start);
  if (Number.isInteger(number) === true) {
    while (number != 1) {
      if (number % 3 === 0) {
        number / 3;
        document.getElementById("answer").append(number + "/3");
      } else if ((number - 1) % 3 === 0) {
        number = number - 1;
        document.getElementById("answer").append(number + "-1");
      } else if ((number + 1) % 3 === 0) {
        number = number + 1;
        document.getElementById("answer").append(number + "+1");

      } else {
        document.getElementById("answer").append(number + "done");
      }
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Please enter a WHOLE NUMBER";
  }
}
```

Comment: `number / 3;` <- what should this do??

Comment: Divide the variable number by 3

Comment: `number / 3;` --> `number = number / 3;`

Comment: You're missing the assignement : `number = number / 3`

Comment: You need to assign the result of that to number -  `number = number /3;`

Comment: The assignment damnit!! :P

Comment: that's a no-op you'd have to do `number /= 3`

Comment: Would have caught this simple error if you debugged :) Remember, developer tools will save your life. Use them. (you can set break points in code, and if you set one after that statement, you'd see it didn't get divided by).

Comment: Thank you, someday ill be good at coding but today is not yet that day.

Comment: We've all been there, just try to use debugging more. One of the greatest secrets of a great developer.

Comment: Nah @JustinThyme even "good" developers make those mistakes.. Dont worry you are not a machine, you are human!